# A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I need to fit `RandomForestRegressor` from `sklearn.ensemble`.

```
forest = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(**RF_tuned_parameters)
model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y)
yhat = model.predict(test_fold)
```

This code always worked until I made some preprocessing of data (`train_y`).
The error message says:

> DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for example using ravel().
>
> model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y)

Previously `train_y` was a Series, now it's numpy array (it is a column-vector). If I apply `train_y.ravel()`, then it becomes a row vector and no error message appears, through the prediction step takes very long time (actually it never finishes...).

In the docs of `RandomForestRegressor` I found that `train_y` should be defined as `y : array-like, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]`
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: what is `train_fold.shape` and `train_y.shape`?

Comment: @Alexander: train_fold: tuple (749904,24)... train:y.ravel(): tuple (749904,)

Comment: Looks fine.  Have you tried training a 100 rows of the data to ensure it works properly (since you said it never finished)?  Also, have you examined the contents of your `train_y` data to ensure preprocessing didn't corrupt it?

Comment: Print `RF_tuned_parameters` for us please.

Comment: @imaluengo: {'n_estimators': 40, 'max_features': 0.8, 'n_jobs': 2, 'verbose': True, 'min_samples_split': 6, 'random_state': 123}

Comment: @Alexander doesnt need to be. Documentation says that float is treated as a percentage. However @KlausosKlausos, can you try with `max_features='sqrt'`, just in case some bug. Also, which version of sklearn do you have?

Comment: @Alexander: Everything works with 100 entries. But with the whole set it lasts forever...

Comment: OK.  Use %timeit to check for performance difference using 10k rows using both your old method and your new method (using the same RF_tuned_parameters).  You can even use `old_Y_series.values.ravel()` to get it in the same format as what you are currently using. Is the transformation of the Y values itself responsible for the extra computational time?

Comment: did the data type change from the original series? you could put it back as a series (using `pd.Series(train_y)` and try again?) Also what was your preprocessing of `y`? Finally 750K rows is a very large data set, i would expect this to take a long time to train, possibly on the order of hours.

Comment: @maxymoo: Surprisingly it takes 7 minutes to train, BUT prediction takes a very long time. Actually Ive been waiting for few hours and didn't get a result. It's strange, because fitting must take longer time than predicting.

Comment: @Alexander: I eliminated max_features and now it's a moment to run the prediction. Hmm, but very strange why this happened.

Comment: Are any of the solutions correct? If so, can you please mark one as such?

Answer (score 393):

Change this line:

```
model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y)
```

to:

```
model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y.values.ravel())
```

*Explanation:*

`.values` will give the values in a `numpy` array (shape: (n,1))

`.ravel` will convert that array shape to (n, ) (i.e. flatten it)

Comment: Someone might explain what it actually changes.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: If you have a numpy.ndarray, then use train_y.ravel() instead.

Comment: @RahulParashar what `ravel()` does is: when you have `y.shape == (10, 1)`, using `y.ravel().shape == (10, )`. In words... it flattens an array.

Comment: Is this even a useful warning?

Comment: Or assuming the dependent variable in y to be only one, and assuming the training_test from sklearn was used, you can access straight to the only one column in the dataset as y['whatever_your_feature_is']

Comment: I got the same message for SVM. Being new to machine learning, I didn't knew how to use ravel. Thanks for giving a short explanation for it

Answer (score 28):

I also encountered this situation when I was trying to train a **KNN** classifier. but it seems that the warning was gone after I changed:
`knn.fit(X_train,y_train)`
to
`knn.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train,order='C'))`

Ahead of this line I used `import numpy as np`.

Comment: When using the `.ravel()` approach my column vector was converter to a row vector rather than an array, but this fix worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. The problem was that the labels were in a column format while it expected it in a row.
use `np.ravel()`

```
knn.score(training_set, np.ravel(training_labels))
```

Hope this solves it.

Comment: You mean `np.ravel()`?

Answer (score 14):

use below code:

```
model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y.ravel())
```

if you are still getting slap by error as identical as below ?

```
Unknown label type: %r" % y
```

use this code:

```
y = train_y.ravel()
train_y = np.array(y).astype(int)
model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y)
```

Comment: This worked for me, dont know the background working. Still, I feel like I can explore what was it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Y = y.values[:,0]

Y - formated_train_y

y - train_y
```

Comment: Please add a few lines to explain your answer, just posting the code does not do any good to any of the readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this is to use `ravel`

```
model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y.values.reshape(-1,))
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that this will work for Pandas Series, but not Pandas DataFrames.

Answer (score 2):

With [neuraxle](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle), you can easily solve this :

```
p = Pipeline([
   # expected outputs shape: (n, 1)
   OutputTransformerWrapper(NumpyRavel()), 
   # expected outputs shape: (n, )
   RandomForestRegressor(**RF_tuned_parameters)
])

p, outputs = p.fit_transform(data_inputs, expected_outputs)
```

Neuraxle is a sklearn-like framework for hyperparameter tuning and AutoML in deep learning projects !

Comment: NumpyRavel throws exception when using it in an AutoML search.

Answer (score 1):

```
format_train_y=[]
for n in train_y:
    format_train_y.append(n[0])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
use

```
y = np.squeeze(y)
```

instead of

```
y = y.ravel()
```

As Python's `ravel()` may be a valid way to achieve the desired results in this particular case, I would, however, recommend using `numpy.squeeze()`.
The problem here is, that if the shape of your `y` (numpy array) is e.g. `(100, 2)`, then `y.ravel()` will concatenate the two variables on the second axis along the first axis, resulting in a shape like `(200,)`. This might not be what you want when dealing with independent variables that have to be regarded on their own.
On the other hand, `numpy.squeeze()` will just trim any redundant dimensions (i.e. which are of size 1). So, if your numpy array's shape is `(100, 1)`, this will result in an array of shape `(100,)`, whereas the result for a numpy array of shape `(100, 2)` will not change, as none of the dimensions have size 1.