# DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I keep having an error running this part of my code:

```
scores = cross_val_score(XGB_Clf, X_resampled, y_resampled, cv=kf)
```

The error is :

> DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array
>   was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for
>   example using ravel().   y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

I know there are lots of answers to this question, and that I need to use `ravel()`, but using it does not change anything!

Also, the array "y" I'm passing to the function is ***not*** a *column-vector* ...

See:

```
y_resampled
Out[82]: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

When I run

```
y_resampled.ravel()
```

I get

```
Out[81]: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

which is exactly the same as my initial variable...

Also, when I run `y_resampled.values.ravel()` I get an error telling me that this is well a numpy array...

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<ipython-input-80-9d28d21eeab5>", line 1, in <module>
y_resampled.values.ravel()
```

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Does any one of you have a solution to this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After several days, I still cannot go over this issue.. I needed to ignore the warning directly in my code to get over it.. I really don't like this solution! Does anybody have an answer to this ? Thanks a lot... !

Comment: That is pretty weird.

I have definitely seen some variance across the different model (and related) classes in scikit-learn with respect to these warnings. For example, I can pass a one-column'ed DataFrame into a LinearRegression object as y and there will be no warning. On the other hand, if I do this with an MLPRegressor I will get a warning, unless I pass only that column's values (a NumPy array).

Comment: As for your specific issue: yes the ravel function won't change that array because ravel is meant to basically flatten or unroll a matrix into a 1d array. Also, regrading your attempted usage of the values attribute: that is what you'd expect too, as values returns the values of a DataFrame or Series as a NumPy array, and seeing as how you already have one, that won't work.

I would ask what versions of sklearn and numpy you're running? Upgrading might not be a bad idea, pending any dependencies, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165731/a-column-vector-y-was-passed-when-a-1d-array-was-expected) man!

Simply:

```
model = forest.fit(train_fold, train_y.values.ravel())
```

Answer (score 0):

in you write y_resampled as dataframe, you can use values function.

```
import pandas as pd
y_resampled = pd.DataFrame(y_resampled)
```